# ModelBinding a List of Editable Integers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a view that looks like this:

```
@model List<int>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<ul>
@{int counter = 0;}
@foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[counter])</li>
    counter++;
}
</ul>
}
```

my problem is that the generated html looks like this...

```
    <li><input name="[0]" type="text" value="1" /></li>
etc.. etc...
```

When I post back to the controller, the form names don't bind to a my controller. Any thoughts on how to fix it (prefix or something perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago, and this is my solution (workaround?)

You can use this code in your view to generate the form:

```
@Html.TextBox("number[" + counter + "]", i)
```

And in your controller define action with `List<int> number` parameter

```
public ActionResult Index(List<int> number) { ... }
```

I have never tried to find out why the simple solution doesn't work, but I guess, that model binder needs some property name to work with.